# Documentation link issue in toctree

Tags: python, python-sphinx, toctree

I have one file with the following content.

```
.. toctree::
   :includehidden:
   :titlesonly:

   Getting_started <./docs/Getting_started>
```

Which gives the `Getting_started` link as

`href="docs/Getting_started.html"` but I want to have this link as below

`href="/docs/Getting_started.html"`

Is it possible with sphinx? Please help

Comment: Did you try removing the leading `.`?

Comment: No. Let me try to

Comment: @StevePiercy, that didn't work

Comment: What was the output? Also update your question with your docs directory structure.